# quantum correlation and Bell inequalities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

when i read about quantum correlation , its written that quantum entanglement violates bell inequalities. 
But in every book we always take bell states as a example of entanglement. I am cofused that either bell states are classically correlated or quantum correlated ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show enough previous research.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum correlated. Bell states violate Bell inequalities.